# Разместить блок по центру

Tags: css

Здравствуйте возникла проблема с корректным центрированием блока, так чтобы на разных устройствах (телефон, компьютер, планшет), он размещался по центру, а сам текст в них был выровнен, по левому краю, вот пример:

```
<section>

    <!-- Это блок нужно выровнять по центу (по вертикали и горизонтали) от родительского элемента -->
    <div class="info">
         <p class="title>Заголовок</p>
         <p class="description">Описание</p>
    <div>

</section>
```

Пробовал использовать margin, но на разных устройствах совершенно разный результат...

Answer (score 1):

Все что внутри в данном случае `section` будет по центру:

```
section {
  width: 400px; /* или проценты */
  height: 200px; /* или проценты */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Для текста просто `text-align: left;`. По дефолту left.

Comment: Не работает... Элементы выстраиваются в ряд, как будто бы я задал .title и .description свойство float : left

Comment: Нужно больше деталей. Стили CSS для классов/элементов, валидный html код (без ошибок). Мне так не понять в чем проблема. На простом примере все работает: https://jsfiddle.net/4x0toxq8/1/